# iBeacon with database calls in the background?

Tags: ios7, background, ibeacon

I'm making an iBeacon based app for a shopping mall with notifications based specifically on which store is nearby.
My question is, with background tasks in iOS 7.1 and above, can I run database calls(to reference location on the basis of the closest beacon). What about network calls(like a PFQuery?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do anything you want on iBeacon detection in the background including database access and web service calls.  I have developed apps doing both of these things.  The only trick is that iOS only gives your app 5-10 seconds of running time after the detection takes place, so you must make these operations relatively fast.

Comment: Do you have some (even if they're partial)examples of code you could direct me to?
Thanks in Advance.